# How do I get all bars in a matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It is easy to retrieve all lines in a line chart by calling the `get_lines()` function. I cannot seem to find an equivalent function for a barchart, that is retrieving all Rectangle instances in the `AxesSubplot`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want all bars, just capture the output from the plotting method. Its a list containing the bars:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)

bars = ax.bar(x, y, color='grey')    
bars[3].set_color('g')
```

[image]

If you do want all Rectangle object in the axes, but these can be more then just bars, use:

```
bars = [rect for rect in ax.get_children() if isinstance(rect, mpl.patches.Rectangle)]
```

Comment: I would if I could, but unfortunately pandas only returns AxesSubplot, and not the bars instances. Thanks!

Comment: Good point, i don't think its possible if you plot from Pandas to only get the bars which are just plotted. Filtering by plotting with a unique property (like facecolor) would work, but isn't fancy. :)

Comment: for pandas people: `ax.patches` will just give you the bars --`ax.get_children()` return extra objects as well.

Comment: ^ `ax.patches` also returns patches in the legend.

Answer (score 4):

Another option that might be useful to some people is to access `ax.containers`. You have to be a little careful though as if your plot contains other types of containers you'll get those back too. To get just the bar containers something like

```py
from matplotlib.container import BarContainer
bars = [i for i in ax.containers if isinstance(i, BarContainer)]
```

This can be pretty powerful with a few tricks (taking inspiration from the accepted example).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(2, 5)

ax.bar(x, y[0], width=0.5)
ax.bar(x + 0.5, y[1], width=0.5)

for bar, color in zip(ax.containers, ("red", "green")):
    # plt.setp sets a property on all elements of the container
    plt.setp(bar, color=color)
```

will give you:

[image]

If you add some labels to your plots you can construct a dictionary of containers to access them by label

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(2, 5)

ax.bar(x, y[0], width=0.5)
ax.bar(x + 0.5, y[1], width=0.5, label='my bars')

named_bars = {i.get_label(): i for i in ax.containers}
plt.setp(named_bars["my bars"], color="magenta")
```

will give you

[image]

Of course, you can still access an individual bar patch within a container e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(2, 5)

ax.bar(x, y[0], width=0.5)
ax.bar(x + 0.5, y[1], width=0.5)

plt.setp(ax.containers[0], color="black")
plt.setp(ax.containers[1], color="grey")
ax.containers[0][3].set_color("red")
```

[image]