# How to get colors of pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I get the colors of the elements in a pandas bar plot?

Example: I have a bar plot with historic data for a couple of columns. Now I want to plot a horizontal line with the mean value of each column in the same color as the bars.

This question discusses access to colors of matplotlib line plots: [How to get color of most recent plotted line in Python's plt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699155/how-to-get-color-of-most-recent-plotted-line-in-pythons-plt)

It allowed to me to get the colors of line plots, but not bar plots. I suppose there could be an equivalent to `get_lines()`, but I cannot find it.

```
"""Access bar plot colors."""

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
ax = df.plot()

# This works fine for line plots
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    color = ax.get_lines()[i].get_color()
    print(color)


ax = df.plot(kind='bar')

# This does not work: "IndexError: list index out of range"
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    color = ax.get_lines()[i].get_color()
    print(color)
```

Comment: This question and its answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22688915/11946287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.patches`:

```
>>> ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
>>> print(ax.patches)
[<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x7f02e2ba3760>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x7f02e2ba35e0>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x7f02e2ba3dc0>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x7f02e2ba35b0>]
>>> for i, col in enumerate(df):
...     color = ax.patches[i].get_facecolor()
...     print(color)
...
(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0)
(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0)
```

However as you can see enumerating them doesn’t tell you which patch corresponds to which data. Here we’ve grabbed 2 rectangles of the same color. Therefore I would recommend the `.get_legend_handles_labels()` function that is used to build legends:

```
>>> print(ax.get_legend_handles_labels())
([<BarContainer object of 2 artists>, <BarContainer object of 2 artists>], ['col1', 'col2'])
>>> for bars, column in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels()):
...     color = bars[0].get_facecolor()
...     print(column, color)
...
col1 (0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0)
col2 (1.0, 0.4980392156862745, 0.054901960784313725, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would change it around and plot the data yourself explicitly, instead of trying to piece out what you need afterwards from the returned axes. But Cimbali already showed how you *can* do that, if needed.

It's a little bit more code, but calling `ax.bar` yourself allows you to capture the return value.

For example plot with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

idx = df.index.values

width = 0.25
col1_bars = ax.bar(idx - width/2, 'col1', width, label='Col1', data=df)
col2_bars = ax.bar(idx + width/2, 'col2', width, label='Col2', data=df)

ax.set_xticks(idx)
ax.legend(loc=2)
```

You can then extract the colors, or any other property of the bars, by examining the returned `BarContainer` objects:

```
col1_colors = list(map(lambda x: x.get_facecolor(), col1_bars))
col2_colors = list(map(lambda x: x.get_facecolor(), col2_bars))
```

Comment: I must say I usually do this for timeseries anyways, as pandas’ automatic display of time on the x-axis used to be quite rubbish (and is frankly still a little unwieldy). This is the better way if you want more control on what you plot.

Comment: Yes me too. The built-in plotting methods from Pandas (and many other packages like Xarray etc) are great for quick exploration but I usually find myself ending up with "bare" Matplotlib anyway as soon as it needs to get fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers by Rutger and Cimbali, I came up with my own solution, which I leave here for reference: It possible to find the correct BarContainer and get the color that way. But Cimbali's use of get_legend_handles_labels() might be more elegant. :-)

```py
"""Access bar plot colors."""

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

# This works fine for line plots
ax = df.plot()
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    color = ax.get_lines()[i].get_color()
    print(color)
    ax.axhline(y=df[col].mean(), label=col+' (mean)', linestyle='--', c=color)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Now try with bar plot: Access color via BarContainer
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    color = ax.containers[i][0].get_facecolor()
    ax.axhline(y=df[col].mean(), label=col+' (mean)', linestyle='--', c=color)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Now try with bar plot: Access color via get_legend_handles_labels()
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
for bars, col in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels()):
    color = bars[0].get_facecolor()
    ax.axhline(y=df[col].mean(), label=col+' (mean)', linestyle='--', c=color)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]